# Allow ECMASCRIPT 8 on JShint

Tags: node.js, jshint

I am trying to use Mariadb ECMAScript 2017 API but it seems that it isn't supported by the JShint linter.

I tried to change the the ECMASCRIPT version at `settings.json` but when I do that, I get that the only versions allowed are 3, 5, 6.

This are the settings I mentioned:

```
"jshint.options": {
  "esversion": 6
}
```

I don't want the linter to throw warnings because of async function declaration.

Comment: The `esversion` should accept a value in the range [3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], according to the doc : https://jshint.com/docs/options/#esversion Also, async functions are part of ES6, so you should not get any error.

Comment: Very weird... check at these: https://ibb.co/MRGkL9r

Comment: Also: https://imgur.com/a/bd69Kdb

Comment: On your second screenshot, this tooltip is most likely linked to the VSCode extension, which might not be up to date. There is an issue about that in the github repo : https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jshint/issues/74, but the author seem to be inactive. I guess you can still safely use the `8` value, since JSHint itself supports it.

Comment: Definitely what’s going on haha, just gonna ignore it.